# how to format 'YYYY-MM-DD' to 'DD.MM.YYYY' in Vue template

Tags: vue.js

help, I need to format date 'YYYY-MM-DD' to 'DD.MM.YYYY' in vue js
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a JavaScript date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write like this by using momentjs.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  {{ moment(item.createdAt,'YYYY-MM-DD').format("DD.MM.YYYY") }}
</div>
```